# The Aseity or Lack Thereof of the Son and the Holy Spirit with the Assumption of Classical Trinitarianism

Tags: persons-of-the-trinity, aseity

Assuming Trinitarianism and the eternal generation and eternal procession of the Son and the Holy Spirit respectively to be true, do the Son and the Holy Spirit possess the attribute of aseity? If so, how exactly do they? Do they only possess it in their divine nature, which is equal to that of the Father? Or, do they possess it both in their hypostases and nature? I have been thinking through this and have come to believe that they only possess it in their divine nature, but I really want to hear what others have to say on this to make sure I am not missing anything.

Comment: When you say "their hypostases" what are you referring to?

Comment: Is this the definition of aseity that you understand:  God's aseity means that he is sufficient to himself, independent of anything outside himself?

Comment: I am really sorry for not being as clear as I should have been. In my question, I am using the term "hypostases" to refer to the individual and unique person of the Son and that of the Holy Spirit. Mike Borden, that is part of the way I understand it. In addition to that, I would also add the quality of being self-originated.

Comment: Given that the Creator God alone is 'self-originated' (all other things originating from him) it cannot be logical to then speak of the Son, and the Holy Spirit as also being 'self-originated' for then you would have three beings, all three supposed to be 'self-originated'. But the Trinity doctrine rules out three beings: there's only one. So, this comment is just to seek clarification as to your last sentence, above, to Mike Borden.

Comment: The Son, according to classical Trinitarian doctrine, is eternally begotten and therefore not self-originated even though He has no beginning.

Answer (score 2):

Essence answers the question "what is this thing?"

A proof for God which reveals something about God's essence is St Thomas' [third way](https://www.newadvent.org/summa/1002.htm#article2). The gist is that everything in existence has its *reason for being* in something else. In other words, everything we see seems to lack aseity (or, they are contingent). But if *everything* lacked aseity, then at some point nothing would have existed, and therefore something would have had to have come from nothing. This is absurd. Therefore there has to be something which is has its reason for being in itself, and we refer to this being as God.

Notice that the Trinity or Personhood is not brought up in that proof, but we  just showed that God's essence *is* His existence. This is because we are speaking of *being*, and as we know God is only 1 being. The Persons don't "share" parts of the Divine Nature; to say otherwise is either a sort of [Sabellianism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sabellianism) or polytheism. Each of the Persons is God, and not a separate being.

But to say that the Son (or Spirit) has His reason for being in Himself, seems to imply that the Son is a separate being. And so the *Persons* of the Trinity are described in relation *to each other*.

Comment: Thus, you would agree with the formulation I provided in my question?

Comment: Are you referring to "they possess it both in their hypostases and nature"? @hihi

Comment: I am referring to "I have been thinking through this and have come to believe that they only possess it in their divine nature. . ." By "their divine nature", I mean that one nature that they and the Father each fully have.

Comment: Then yes I believe I would agree with that.